# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer while for Loop in Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to iterate through 1 column of unlimited rows depending on if there's data in the row's cell, and append the cell value of each row in column A to a list. My sheet has headers.

Code:

```
wspath = 'Path\\'
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(wspath)
    ws1 = wb['Sheet1']
    
    oplist = []
    
    for row in ws1.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws1.min_row,ws1.max_row)):
        for cell in row:
             oplist.append(cell.value)
    print(oplist)
```

I get this error: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I am trying to iterate through 1 column of unlimited rows depending on if there's data in the row's cell, and append the cell value of each row in column A to a list. My sheet has headers.

Comment: Could you add some additional information? The full error message should include which line of code the error is located.

Comment: `ws.iter_rows()` takes numerical parameters. `min_row` and `max_row` don't need to be specified. `ws.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1)` would suffice. Or `ws["A"]`. This is all covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way to do this.

Using Pandas, I'm able to read the sheet into a DF and convert it into a list.

`wspath = r'FilePath' wb = pd.read_excel(wspath,sheet_name=0)   oplist = wb[ColumnName(s)].tolist()`